# using loop to hide ribbon controls vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a table for user screens.

UserID - ScreenID - Perm

I need to hide controls when the form opens with UserID and ScreenID, and I can't use the loop with condition.

This is my code:

```
Try
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    If dbconnect.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then dbconnect.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UserScreens WHERE UserID='" & UserID & "'", dbconnect)
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim M As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
        For Each ctrl As Control In Ribbon1.Controls
            ctrl.Visible = M.Item("Perm")
        Next
        'DocIDtxt.Text = M.Item("DOCID")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    If dbconnect.State = ConnectionState.Open Then dbconnect.Close()
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: Is Perm a boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

I always worry about connections first. From MS docs

"The IDbConnection object associated with the select command must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the IDbConnection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open."

What that means is you opened your connection before the .Fill method so it will remain open. Bad! The only way your code closes the connection is if there is an error. A Finally section with .Close in your Try...End Try would do the trick but better yet use Using...End Using. This block will ensure that your objects are closed and disposed properly even if there is an error. When an object has a Dispose method it may have unmanaged resources that it must clean up.

Next, turn on Option Strict. It will be a great help pointing potential runtime errors.

Third, always use Parameters.

See inline explanation and comments.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
        Try
            'A DataTable does not have a Dispose() method so it will fall
            'out of scope and be garbage collected.
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            'SqlConnection has a Dispose() method so use Using
            Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
                'SqlCommand has a Dispose() method so use Using
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserScreens WHERE UserID= @UserID", cn)
                    'Always use Parameters. Never concatenate strings in SQL statements.
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserID
                    cn.Open()
                    'SqlDataReader has a Dispose() method so use Using
                    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        dt.Load(dr)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim M As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
                For Each ctrl As Control In Ribbon1.Controls
                    'If Perm is not a boolean this line of code can't work
                    ctrl.Visible = CBool(M.Item("Perm"))
                Next
                'DocIDtxt.Text = M.Item("DOCID")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```